# How to get real NAND Storage Space?

Tags: android, capacity, flash-memory

The storage shown by PlayStore applications is not the real IC flash memory capacity.

It shows the space occupied by system and some internal storage left but the sum is not the full Storage capacity of the IC flash memory.

For now i am disassembling the phone and view the model to get the right value. Is there a method to get the full storage capacity without opening the phone.

It's useful for the end user to view the real capacity of the owned product.

Comment: "It's useful for the end user to view the real capacity of the owned product." -- why? As a user, only usable capacity is *useful*.

Comment: Why you have to buy a product mentioned as 16GB and then you will find 11 GB as total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't provide specific details, but this would in general depend on the file system in use and/or the Flash Translation Layer. Both might keep spare blocks available, periodically free space in a garbage collector run (which might possibly lead to wrong results) etc.

Besides that, it is normal for NAND flash devices to accumulate bad blocks or even be shipped with bad blocks. Those blocks are not usable anymore and are therefore to be deducted from the total (physical) space.

This might be why FS/FTL might keep spare blocks available, to ensure that it will not run out of space during normal operations.